# SwiftUI : WKWebView is there a way to call a function once the WKWebView has finished loading?

Tags: swiftui, wkwebview

Using SWIFTUI and a WKWebView is there a way to call a function once the WKWebView has finished loading ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below delegate method to check for finish page loading.

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) { }
```

Comment: Did not work for me. (I don't have any delegation connected from webView to my class though)